# applying 'display:hidden' to a div at a certain window width using js

Tags: javascript, css, navigation

I am using media queries to make a responsive site. That isn't my problem but it is why I am here today with this question.

At a certain browser width, my horizontal navigation at the top of my page becomes too wide (becomes squished) and looks awkward in my layout. What I want to do is this: When a users browser reaches a certain min-width, I would like to (using js) hide the horizontal navigation (an unordered list of 6) that originally rendered on the users screen (if you are viewing wider than 650px) and replace it with a single 'button' that when clicked drops down the un-ordered list.

Now, the CSS isnt the problem. I just cant seem to figure out how to do the transition from the original horizontal nav that originally renders, to a more user friendly navigation.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to have 2 sets of navigation mechanisms. Hide one and show the other.

You will need to add an eventlistener on the `resize` event for `document`, where you will check the `innerWidth` of the window and decide which navigation `div` to display.

```
document.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    if (window.innerWidth < 650) {
        document.getElementById("horizontal_nav").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("dropdown_nav").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("dropdown_nav").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("horizontal_nav").style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can keep your horizontal navigation but specify a `max-width` of `650px`, once this has been reached, it will stop growing.

```
div#horizontal_nav {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 650px;
}
```

Comment: Might want to attach to the onload event as well, in case the browser is already shrunk down

Comment: I am trying to implement your first solution, thanks for that.

The second solution wont help because if the screen is about 700 then the nav is on the left side not at the top

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these can help:

http://www.bram.us/2011/10/24/jquery-mobile-select-jquery-mobile-navigation-replacement-plugin/

https://github.com/joggink/jquerymobiledropdown

I know. It´s jQuery but I hope ppl get the general idea.